# Testing routes to give same results on every request chai/mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I need my test to check that once a GET request on a route was made (it generates and gives a UUID) it will give the same response on every run.

E.g : 
Let's assume we made a request and it gave us this result:

`{"prop1":"79de8657-67d0-40cd-88d0-129bf7b22837","prop2":"hello world"}`

and later, on this same running server it should give out this result on every run.

Everything works properly, but I need to setup a test. 
What I have is this:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const server = require('../index');

const should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('/GET id', () => {
   it('should give out the same id on every request', (done) => {
       const result1 = chai.request(server).get('/id');
       const result2 = chai.request(server).get('/id');


      //
   })
});
```

How do I combine theese two results to be equal and consider the test done and 'passed'?
Can't get my head around it.

Comment: I've checked and discovered that result1 or result2 give out promises, but what i need is a value, retrieved from a request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `expect(result1).to.equal(result2);`. THis should test that.